# Affinity Designer: How do I make textframes scale with the artboard if I scale by an exact value?

Tags: text, resize, affinity-designer

When scaling artboards "by hand" with the "scale handle", the font-size of textframes changes as expected. However if I use the transform dialogue to enter an exact value I want the artboard to scale to, the font-size does not increase but only the area of the text-frame. It is the same as I would use the "normal" handles if I were to scale "by hand" instead of the "scale handle" (for the lack of better words).

Here is a gif detailing the issue:
[image: gif showing different scale behaviours in affinity designer]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/36998-how-to-make-text-resize/&do=findComment&comment=182969) on the official Affinity forums, that is the expected behavior:

> You can't use the Transform panel to set the dimensions directly because the text frames will reflow instead of being scaled.
>
> - [MEB (Moderator), *Affinity on Desktop Questions*](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/36998-how-to-make-text-resize/&do=findComment&comment=182969)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

Scale manually. Have the content grouped and use the handle which scales the content, too. Have another artboard which has exact dimensions and snap to it.